# JSON as HTML tooltip value - display without brackets / with br

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using my prepared json object in JAVA. I just wanted to display values of object as:

```
<uib-progress ng-if="month.data" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{month.dataTest|json}}">
    <uib-bar stuff>
    </uib-bar>                                       
</uib-progress>
```

As you can see, I implemented |json format to add "br" between values. But still, it looks ugly as my tooltip:

```
[
 {
  "from":"2017-01-01",
  "to":"2017-02-02"
 },
 {
  "from":"2017-01-01",
  "to":"2017-02-02"
 }
]
```

It is possible to delete brackets by using additional code in html?
Or I have to prepare it in JAVA?

Comment: You can define your own filter to remove brackets

Comment: Yeah I've got filter like this:   return function (text) {
        return text ? String(text).replace(/^{}+/i, '') : '';
    } , but it can't work with { } [] brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace any sign easy in js:

```
var string = 'GL123456'; // just an example
string.replace(/^GL+/i, ''); '123456'
```

Comment: But how to replace all [, {, }, ] signs? When I replaced GL with any of them, just have [object object], [object object] from my json

Comment: You can convert json to string.

var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);

And then after editing your string, convert it again to JSON:
obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);

good luck:)

Comment: Maybe it's stupid question, but better is to do it in app.filter or maybe in function like deleteBrackets()?

Comment: @Kondziowsky as for me, it should be deleteBrackets(). more readable.